# Snakemake + tmux

Tags: snakemake

My workflow often includes PBS job submissions to a shared cluster that need to either wait in the scheduling queue, take over 24hrs to run or both. I'd like to run `snakemake` in the 'background' and get my prompt back while these jobs are running. I know this can be done using `tmux`, `screen`, or `&` but is there is a better way to do this?

I guess submitting a bash wrapper script with the `snakemake` commands inside is an option but I think I'm lacking some understanding of the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmux` is the recommended way to execute a Snakemake workflow. It will give you all you need, regardless of whether you are in a cluster or on a compute server.